Problem with ngrx while tried to login with correct username and password
I am trying to create a login page. I am using angular with ngrx for state management.
login.action.ts
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";


export const loginRequest = createAction(
    '[Login] Login Request',
    props<{ credential: { emailId: string; password: string }}>()
)

export const loginSuccess = createAction(
    '[Login] Login Success',
    props<{ loginResponse: string }>()
)

export const loginFailure = createAction(
    '[Login] Login Failuer',
    props<{ error: string }>()
)

login.effect.ts
import { inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from "@ngrx/effects";
import { AccountService } from "../../_services/account.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import * as AuthActions from '../actions/login.action';
import { catchError, exhaustMap, map, of, tap } from "rxjs";

Injectable()

export class AuthEffects {

    private actions$ = inject(Actions);
    private authService = inject(AccountService);
    private router = inject(Router);

    loginRequest$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(AuthActions.loginRequest),
            exhaustMap((action) => 
                this.authService
                    .login({userName: action.credential.emailId, password: action.credential.password})
                    .pipe(
                        map((loginResponse) => AuthActions.loginSuccess({loginResponse: loginResponse.firstName})),
                        catchError((error) => of(AuthActions.loginFailure({error: error.message})))
                    )
                )
            )
        );

    loginSuccess$ = createEffect(
        () => 
            this.actions$.pipe(
                ofType(AuthActions.loginSuccess),
                tap(({ loginResponse }) => {
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/register');
                })
            )
    );
}

login.reducer.ts
import { Action, createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import { LoginResponse } from "../../_models/LoginResponse";
import * as AuthActions from '../actions/login.action';

const initialAuthState: LoginResponse = {
    username: "",
    firstName: "",
    token: "",
    lastName: "",
    photoUrl: ""
};

export const _authReducer = createReducer(initialAuthState, 
    on(AuthActions.loginRequest, state => ({...state, isLoading: true, error: null})),
    on(AuthActions.loginSuccess, (state, { loginResponse }) => ({ ...state, isLoading: false, loginResponse })),
    on(AuthActions.loginFailure, (state, { error }) => ({...state, isLoading: false, error}))
);

export function authReducer(state: LoginResponse | undefined, action: Action)
{
    console.log('State: ', state);
    console.log('Action: ', action);
    return _authReducer(state, action);
}

My problem is when I tried to login with valid username and password login success effect is not getting called and the state is not getting changed. When I checked the console logs I saw that login success reducer is not mapped the action and it becomes an infinite loop.
This is the log reference
I don't know where I am doing wrong. I am new in this ngrx framework.
Version Which I have used:
Angular: 18.2.0
Ngrx: 18.0.2
Version details
Expectation is once successful login happened the state should changed with proper details from database

the problem is this effect
loginSuccess$ = createEffect(
        () => 
            this.actions$.pipe(
                ofType(AuthActions.loginSuccess),
                tap(({ loginResponse }) => {
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/register');
                })
            )
    );

the stream is catching loginSuccess action and emits loginSuccess action - which creates a loop for this effect again.
to fix that add dispatch: false to an effect config
createEffect(() => ...., {dispatch: false});

